# Multiplying two 32-bit registers and using the result in an other multiplying operation

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to write an exponentiation subroutine using fast exponentiation. I will use multiplication results again and again. When I multiply it, the result becomes edx:eax.

When I try to multiply the result with another value, how can I do it?

Comment: Will the result be more than 32 bits? Do you need to save/use the hight dword in multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need 32-bit products from multiplication of 32-bit multiplicands, you simply discard/ignore the part of the product in `edx`, assuming there's no overflow or you're doing your arithmetic modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. If you need the product modulo some other value, say, 10<sup>9</sup>, you then divide the product by it and take the remainder.

It's hard to be more specific given the general question.